# iPhone Hotspot: who is connected?

Tags: iphone, tethering

Sometimes, when I start to use my iPhone as a hotspot, I see 2 connections. Since I am the only one supposed to be using it, and I’m only using wifi (not USB as well), I can’t work out why there is a second connection.

After a while, it often goes down to 1 connection. I wonder whether the second connection is someone else trying to use it.

The question is: how can I tell who is accessing the hotspot?

BTW, the initial problem was to resolve why I appear to be having more connections than I could account for, and that is indeed covered in another question. However, I would still like to know whether it’s possible to see *who is* actually connected.

Comment: @owlswipe The problem is that I wanted to to see _who_ is connected to my hotspot. Your answer explains why there are more connections that I expected, and that was helpful, which is why I have upvoted it. I would still like to see a list of connections.

Comment: Understood, thanks :D. I'm pretty sure that's not possible, but idrk...

Answer (score 3):

Other devices (including iPads, iPods, Macs, and other iPhones) connected to the same iCloud account as your iPhone will, if in WiFi range, automatically connect to your iPhone's hotspot when it's turned on ([according to this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18564?locale=en_US) and my personal experience). That means if any of your other devices are lying around, they will automatically connect to your iPhone's hotspot using iCloud.

**tl;dr**: Other devices tied to the same iCloud account might automatically be joining your iPhone's hotspot network.

Comment: That’s quite possible, as I also have an iPad nearby. I will need to check later today to see whether it is attempting to connect. I’d still like to know whether it’s possible to see who is connected, though.

Comment: Well, golly, it seems that my iPad is indeed joining in. That could also explain why there is a connection after I close my laptop, so I don’t have to be so paranoid about it. It’s a good thing that I have a shared data plan …

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of "how can I tell who is accessing the hotspot?"

Comment: @ChrisCalo Sadly, there isn't a way :(. This is merely the probable cause.

Answer (score -3):

When we use use bluetooth and usb wire at the same time while setting up hotspot, it will show 2 connections... if we remove usb cable it will show 1 connection... not to worry...nobody else is using your hotspot .... relax...

Comment: The OP specifically stated they weren't using USB.